# iMac Apple M1 Chip macOS Monterey Java Error for RJDemetra Package in RStudio

Tags: java, r, apple-m1, rjava

I have been using this computer for 3 days. I installed Java from official website. And then i installed the package "RJDemetra" for seasonal adjustments. When i try to activate package i see this warning message on screen.

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RJDemetra’:
.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
call: dyn.load(jli, FALSE)
error: shared object '/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib' could not be loaded:
dlopen(/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib, 0x000A): tried: '/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e'))
```

I am not an advanced Apple Computer user. I have tried all of the suggestions before, did not work.

Comment: Try to download rosetta.
If you have downloaded rosetta, try to download an arm64 version of java.
If these tips don' t work I think that is a library problem

Comment: I saw on the Jdemetra documentation that the library allows only Zulu JDK, Adoptium, Amazon Corretto JDKs. The JDK from the official java website (oracle) is not mentioned. I Suggest you to download the 1.8 Zulu jdk at [this link](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?version=java-8-lts&os=macos&architecture=arm-64-bit&package=jdk)